# openstack keystone reduce number of workers

Tags: openstack, keystone

i tried to reduce the number of keystone work and save some of memory

```
keystone  15467  0.0  0.0 782944 10104 ?        Sl   10:12   0:00 keystone-admin  -DFOREGROUND
keystone  15535  0.0  0.0 782944 10104 ?        Sl   10:12   0:00 keystone-admin  -DFOREGROUND
keystone  15622  1.6  0.2 992416 83788 ?        Sl   10:12   0:01 keystone-main   -DFOREGROUND
keystone  15665  0.0  0.0 782944 10104 ?        Sl   10:12   0:00 keystone-main   -DFOREGROUND
```

there are more than 100 of this kind worker running on my system. I modified the keystone.conf public_workers and admin_workers to 16 only and reboot the system but the number of keystone workers are the same. I am using newton with packstack. please advise ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If *public_workers* and *admin_workers* in **/etc/keystone/keystone.conf** didn't change anything it probably means that your keystone runs under apache (httpd) WSGI. This is how majority of OpenStack distros run keystone now.

So now, depending on your Linux distribution your keystone worker configuration should be under httpd configuration. On Red Hat base systems you will find it in:

1. /etc/httpd/conf.d/10-keystone_wsgi_admin.conf
2. /etc/httpd/conf.d/10-keystone_wsgi_main.conf

Inside you will have line like below or something similar:

> WSGIDaemonProcess keystone_main display-name=keystone-main group=keystone processes=8 threads=8 user=keystone

And this is where you need to change number of processes and threads.